# Spring Boot plugin не добавляет lib folder в jar

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, jar

[Согласно документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-jar-file-structure), исполняемый jar, построенный на основе приложения со spring boot, должен содержать lib папку внутри BOOT-INF:

```
example.jar
 |
 +-META-INF
 +-org
 +-BOOT-INF
    +-classes
    +-lib
       +-dependency1.jar
       +-dependency2.jar
```

Однако jar, собранный с помощью следующего build.gradle файла:

```
group 'as'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    ext {
        springVersion = '5.0.4.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
        springJPAVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
        javaxVersion = '1.0.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'asokp-reports'
    version =  '0.0.1'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': baseName,
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { 
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${springJPAVersion}"
    implementation "javax.persistence:persistence-api:${javaxVersion}"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.43"

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

имеет следующую структуру:

- BOOT-INF

  - classes
- META-INF
- org

Как можно заставить gradle добавить в BOOT-INF папку lib со всеми зависимостями?

Answer (score 0):

возможно нужно добавить еще один репозитарий в buildscript с урлом https://plugins.gradle.org/m2

так же указать стартовый класс

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = 'прописать свой класс'
}
```

остальное на месте.. и выполнить таск bootRepackage